# Load an image from an app directory in Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my `app/` directory, I create sub directory call `Files/`

and I stored all my blogs img in there, now I tried to display in my blade, I couldn't. Is it even possible ?

---

I've tried

**example of my image path**

`/app/Files/blogs/Test/img/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-31%20at%201.35.22%20PM.png`

---

**img tag**

`<img src="{{app_path()}}/Files/blogs/{{$blog->name}}/img/{{$blog->img_path}}">`

---

**Block of code**

```
<ul class="portfolioContainer grid row no_left_right isotope">

        <?php

        use App\Blog;
        $blogs = Blog::all();

        ?>


        @foreach( $blogs as $blog)

        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 isotope-item">
            <div class="lightCon">
              <figure>
                <div class="img_hover">
                <img src="{{app_path()}}/Files/blogs/{{$blog->name}}/img/{{$blog->img_path}}">

                </div>
                <figcaption>
                  <h4><a href="#">{!! $blog->name !!}</a></h4>
                  <div class="metaInfo"> <span>By <a href="#" class="admin"></a> </span> {{ $blog->user->username }}</span></div>
                  <p>{!! $blog->description !!}</p>
                </figcaption>
              </figure>
            </div>
          </li>

        @endforeach

      </ul>
```

Result,

[image]

Console Error
[image]

Any suggestions / hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load an image in the browser, that image needs to be located inside the webroot directory. For Laravel, this is the `public/` directory by default.

So you need to move your `Files` folder and put it inside of `public/`. Then you can simply:

```
<img src="/Files/...
```

You may also find the [`asset()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset) method helpful:

```
<img src="{{ asset('Files/...') }}...
```

Comment: I'do improve this post using `url()` method:  `<img src="{{ url('files/hello.jpg') }}">`

Comment: I tried to avoid placing my stuffs on the **`public`\** directory for a security reason, some people suggesting me to place them in the **`app`\** and get to it using  `app_path()`.  Please correct me - if this is a bad idea.

Comment: @ihue `app_path()` is a method to get the _server side_ path of your Laravel app. That server-side path is not going to be valid to a web browser now is it?

Comment: @ihue, `app/` folder is not for storage porpoises.

Comment: I'll take you guys advice, and I'll throw them in the public directory.

Comment: @manix is `url()` recommended for static assets? I thought that was primarily for building a URL to a Laravel route.

Comment: @jszobody, for lavarel's route you use `route()` method: `<a href="{{ route('post', ['id' => $post->getId()])`. The good thing about use `url()` and `route()` is that you are making your app ready for changes at any server if its domain changes

Comment: @manix Makes sense, that works. Updated the answer. I tend to prefer relative paths myself, which also continue working if the domain changes.

Comment: It should be `asset()` instead of `url()`.

Comment: @user2094178 Yep, you're right, does look like that's the better method. Thanks!